# messages.errorがイメージしてるのと異なるタイミングで表示される

Tags: python, django

開発中のアプリで、会員情報編集機能を実装中です。

**【理想】**

- 会員情報編集が成功：マイページ（membership.html）にもどり、上部にメッセージ表示
- 会員情報編集に失敗：フォーム入力後「編集完了」ボタンをクリック後、会員情報編集ページ上部にメッセージ表示

**【実際おこっていること】**

- 会員情報編集が成功：マイページ（membership.html）にもどってもメッセージは表示されず、管理画面にも情報が反映されていない
- 会員情報編集に失敗：会員情報編集ページにアクセスすると、フォームを入力しなくてもすぐメッセージが表示される

**【解決したいこと】**

1. 会員情報編集に失敗したときのメッセージを正常（理想の流れ）に表示したい
2. 会員情報編集に成功した際、管理画面に情報を反映させたい
3. 会員情報編集に施行したしたときのメッセージを正常（理想の流れ）に表示したい

メッセージの表示は他Viewでも実装しており、そちらは問題なく表示されます。

▽UserChangeView/views.py

```
class UserChangeView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
        template_name = "nagoyameshi/userchange.html"
        success_url = reverse_lazy("nagoyameshi:membership")
    
        def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            form = ProfileForm(request.GET, instance=request.user)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                messages.success(request, "会員情報の変更が完了しました")
                return redirect(self.success_url)
            else:
                print(form.errors)
                messages.error(request, "会員情報の変更に失敗しました")
            return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
    userchange = UserChangeView.as_view()
```

▽forms.py

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model  = User
        fields = ["first_name","last_name","first_name_kana","last_name_kana","email","birthday"]
```

▽admin.py

```
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):

    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('username', 'password')}),
        (_('Personal info'), {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', "customer")}),
        (_('Permissions'), {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'groups', 'user_permissions')}),
        (_('Important dates'), {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')}),
    )

    #管理サイトから追加するときのフォーム
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2'),
        }),
    )

    list_display = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_staff', "customer")
    search_fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email')

admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)
```